# Plan vs. plan on

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between "plan" & "[plan on](https://www.businessinsider.com/inside-secrets-that-ikea-employees-wont-tell-you-2018-4)" in:

> "The store's layout is designed for impulse buys, which might explain why you often buy more than you planned/planned on."

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference to the meaning in your context whether you include a preposition after ***planned*** or not. And if you ***do*** include a preposition, it makes no difference whether you say *...planned **on*** or *...planned **to***. The "deleted" verb from the "parallel construction" could equally well be *...than you **planned on buying*** OR *...than you **planned to buy***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, there's no difference in meaning. The explanation is a little trickier.

The word "plan", as used here in the *intransitive* sense, can optionally be followed by a prepositional phrase *[ "on" + gerund ]* which describes what the plan was about. In your example sentence, this gerund can be omitted (for reasons outside the scope of this question, but the reason would make a good question).

This means there's three equally valid ways of representing the same sentence:

> ... you often buy more things than you planned on buying.
> ... you often buy more things than you planned on.
> ... you often buy more things than you planned.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations!